# Sub query required to avoid aggregate function from counting same values twice

Tags: sql, join, subquery, aggregate, teradata

I have a scenario where I believe multiple joins are causing aggregate functions (a sum, in this case) to count the same values more than once. The data looks something like this;

Table_1

```
Order_ID      Product
1             A
2             B
3             C
4             D
5             A
```

Table_2:

```
Order_ID    Price      
1             10
2             10
3             20
4             20
5             20
```

Table_3

```
Order_ID          etc... etc..
1
2
3
4
5
```

Currently I am doing something like;

```
sel
a.product
,sum (b.price) as Total_Revenue
from Table_1 a

Join table_2 b
on a.order_id = b.order_id

join table_3 c 
on a.order_id = c.order_id

group by 1
```

---

The problem is, instead of returning Total_Revenue as 80, it is returning a result that is nearer double this. I understand from reading other questions that a sub-query might be required, any help on what this might look like? I already tried the below with no luck;

```
left join 
(sel SUM(price) as Total_Revenue
 from table 2) b
 on a.order_id = b.order_id
```

Comment: when you `group by 1` and you're expecting the total revenue to be 80 there's a problem.  could you please post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @zhiguang - group by one is teradata syntax allowing you to group by ordinals, so group by 1 is group by the first column in the query

Comment: Do you have multiple rows per order in any of your tables?

Comment: I fixed it. The issue is that I was getting the message 'Column Order_ID does not exist', because I had not pulled that column in the join/ inner select. So the below fixed it

left join 
(sel 
order id,
SUM(price) as Total_Revenue
 from table 2
group by 1) b
 on a.order_id = b.order_id